# Silverlight XAML namespace scoping

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, combobox

I need to dynamically generate some combo boxes on a silverlight page.

If I have the following xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="Combo1">
  <ComboBox.Items>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Option1" Content="Option 1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Option2" Content="Option 2" />
  </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox Name="Combo2">
  <ComboBox.Items>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Option1" Content="Option 1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Option2" Content="Option 2" />
  </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

I get errors saying that the second Option1 name (under Combo2) already exists in the namespace.

I've read [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/75376.aspx/1) that this is a bug in silverlight, but I couldn't quite understand how to get around it.  I need to be able to retrieve the string Option1 from the selected ComboBox item.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I have a custom control that generates some combo boxes. Some sample XAML code would look like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="Combo1">
  <ComboBox.Items>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="True" Content="Yes" />
    <ComboBoxItem Name="False" Content="No" />
  </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox Name="Combo2">
  <ComboBox.Items>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="True" Content="Okay" />
    <ComboBoxItem Name="False" Content="Not Okay" />
  </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

I want to be able to retrieve the selected ComboBoxItem "Name", not the "Content".. However, doing it like this, I will run into errors if any comboboxitem "Name" is not unique (in this control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same name twice in an XAML/Class file. If you want to dynamically generate a custom combobox, then create a template and use that to dynamically generate the custom combobox or create a custom control that implement combobox.

When doing things like `<ComboBoxItem/>` in the xaml, it's actually calling the constructor of ComboBoxItem to create a ComboBoxItem object. By giving it a name, you can use that to reference  the object in behind-code. So imagine if you have two objects with the same name in the behind-code within the same class....the compiler wouldn't allow you to do that.

The link that you referenced is a bug because you should be able to have the same name if  the objects are in separate classes, so there shouldn't be any naming conflict. But in your case, it seems like you're trying to create two objects with the same name within the same class.

Comment: Thanks.  I just thought <ComboBoxItem Name="..." /> would be encapsulated inside the <ComboBox></ComboBox> element and would not have a namespace issue.

Comment: I guess, what I'm trying to say is, I'm trying to make a custom control that generates its own comboboxes. The comboboxitems of each combo box could be named anything, and thus these comboboxitems can have the same name across different comboboxes. I still need to be able to reference the selected comboboxitems and get their names.

Comment: hmm. What you can do is generate the comboboxes dynamically in the behind-code of your custom control and add it to a stackpanel's children, for example, in your custom control. For each of the combobox control that you created and added to the stackpanel, you can bind an event handler to its "SelectChanged" event so that whenever any of your combobox selected value changed, it'll invoke an event handler method that passes back arguments telling you things like which combobox invoked the event and the new selected value, etc

Comment: Thanks.. Well, that is sort of what I'm doing, generating an xaml string to pass to XamlReader to generate the element, then adding it to my LayoutRoot.  What I'm having difficulty with is that I can't set a "name" for the comboboxitem because it might conflict with the comboboxitems from other comboboxes. I'll update my post to show what I mean.

Comment: It sounds like you just wanted to see what the user selected (Yes/No). When the event handler for the selectedchanged event get invoked, you can just check the new value of the selectedChangeArgs that was passed into the event handler. If the content is "Okay" then do something if it's "not Okay" do something else. I don't see why you would need to give the items a name.

Comment: Thanks.. I need to give them a name because the "Okay" and "Not Okay" strings are to be localized, i.e. they won't always say "Okay" and "Not Okay". It could be a string in a different language. What I need is to be able to retrieve an ID for that choice, could be ID_TRUE, or ID_FALSE, or whatever.. I suppose I could make a note of it myself, was just hoping there was some way of doing this without having to resort to keeping track of which localized string corresponds to which ID..